# JArray.Contains issue

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JArray, read from a file :

```
private void RemoveCatalog(Catalog catalog) {

    System.IO.StreamReader filereader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@appDirectory + "\\list");

    JArray myjarray = JArray.Parse(filereader.ReadToEnd());
    filereader.Close(); 

    string json = " {\"token\":\"" + catalog.Token + "\",\"name\":\"" + catalog.Name +"\",\"logo\":\"" + catalog.Logo + "\",\"theme\":\"" + catalog.Theme + "\"}";

    JObject myCatalogAsJObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    myjarray.Remove(myCatalogAsJObject);

}
```

I want to remove the JObject corresponding to `myCatalogAsJObject` variable, but it doesn't work, because the answer of `myjarray.Contains(myCatalogAsJObject)` is false.

The problem is that `myjarray` actually contains it : it's the only JObject in my JArray.

If I do `myCatalogAsJObject.ToString().Equals(myjarray.First.ToString())`, the answer is true however.

I'm stuck.

Comment: Please note that the problem is not coming from a parsing issue, because if I do `myjarray.Add(myCatalogAsJObject)` and write it to a file, it goes well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.Contains` (and `.Remove`) by default will compare *references*.  Since you're creating a *new* `JObject`, the array does not contain that *instance*.

You *could* get the instance of the object from the array and remove *that*:

```
JObject match = myjarray.FirstOrDefault(j => j.token == catalog.token &&
                                             j.name  == catalog.name  &&
                                             j.logo  == catalog.logo  &&
                                             j.theme == catalog.theme);

myjarray.Remove(match);
```

EDIT : Here is your code, simplified :

```
JToken match = myjarray.FirstOrDefault(j => j.ToString().Equals(myCatalogAsJObject.ToString()));

myjarray.Remove(match);
```

Comment: You beat me to the punch. This is exactly what I wanted to tell.

Comment: Got it, but the JToken class doesn't contain a definitions for token, name, logo and theme attributs... what am I missing here ?

Comment: I found the answer by myself ;). Just need to adapt your code a little bit (in order to compare strings contained by my JTokens). Thanks for your help

Comment: @AdrienBudet Personally, I would not use `ToString()` to compare two objects.  Comparing strings has several nuances (whitespace, casing, etc.) that may cause issues versus comparing fields directly.

Comment: I agree, but in my case it will be fine ;).

Answer (score 3):

As for the `Contains` part of your question, here's my take on a typed `JArray.Contains`:

```
public static bool ContainsTyped<T>(this JArray arr, T item)
{
    return arr.Any(it =>
    {
        T typed;
        try
        {
            typed = it.ToObject<T>();
        }
        catch (JsonException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't parse array item {0} as type {1}: {2}", it, typeof(T), e);
            return false;
        }

        return typed.Equals(item);
    });
}
```

Now simply implement `Equals` on your type (e.g. `Catalog`) and call `arr.ContainsTyped(catalog)`.

Comment: Works very well! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and could not getting it working with the suggested extension method - so I've created an extension that uses `JToken.DeepEquals` which works well.

below is an example

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsJson(this JArray arr, JToken item)
    {
        return arr.Any(it =>
        {
            return JToken.DeepEquals(it, item);
        });
    }
}
```