# Check if string appears in list of JValues

Tags: c#, json

I have some JSON which I inspect and parse into a JArray. The JSON is similar to this :

```
"required" : [ "1", "2" ]
```

Now when it parses, the outcome is an array of JValues. I want to check if my string appears in this list. So, to do this, I do :

```
JArray requiredArray = JArray.Parse(myJson["required].ToString());

bool exists = requiredArray.Contains("1");
```

This comes back as false, and I think its due to it comparing a JValue with a string. I try convert the string to a JValue like so :

```
JValue itemValue = JValue.Parse("1");
```

It doesn't like that, says cannot convert JToken to JValue.

All I need to know is, does my JArray contain this string value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `Any`:

```
bool exists = requiredArray.Any(t => t.Value<string>() == "1");
```

Comment: perfect. Just what i needed, a way to parse either side to make them the same type to compare. Thank you. Will accept when its available

Comment: Don't ask me why it doesn't work in your example code though, I think it should be fine. Maybe something internally in JSON.NET we don't quite understand yet.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the JArray to a string array, that way you'd be able to do .Contains() like you wanted to originally:

```
string[] strings = requiredArray.ToObject<string[]>();

bool exists = strings.Contains("1");
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Contains()` does not work in this case, because as mentioned in [JArray.Contains issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343771/jarray-contains-issue), `JArray`s compare *references* and not the actual *value*. (This is also to answer Patrick's comment in his answer.)

You could do somethin like this:

```cs
public static bool ContainsString(this JArray jArray, string s)
{
    return jArray.Any(x => x.ToString().Equals(s));
}
```

And use it like so:

```cs
if (requiredArray.ContainsString("1")) {
 //...
}
```